# drawing a line between feature points without using "drawmatches" function

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, keypoint

I got the feature points from two consecutive by using different detectors in features2d framework:

In the first frame, the feature points are plotted in red
[image]

In the next frame, the feature points are plotted in blue
[image]

I want to draw a line between these red and blue (matched) points **inside the first frame** (the image with red dots).  ***drawmatches*** function in opencv doesn't help as it shows a window with two consecutive frames next to each other for matching. Is it possible in OpenCV?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you want to visualize how each keypoint moves between two frames. According to my knowledge, there is no built-in function in OpenCV meeting your requirement.

However, as you have called the `drawMatches()` function, you already have the two keypoint sets (take C++ code as example) `vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints1, keypoints2` and the matches `vector<DMatch>& matches1to2`. Then you can get the pixel coordinate of each keypoint from `Point keypoints1.pt` and draw lines between keypoints by calling the `line()` function.

You should be careful that since you want to draw `keypoints2` in the first frame, the pixel coordinate may exceed the size of `img1`.

There is a quick way to get a sense of the keypoints' motion. Below is the result shown by `imshowpair()` in Matlab:
[image]

Comment: that is exactly what i need! thanks a lot. When I decrease the number of features, the motions will be more visible.

Answer (score 1):

After I found good matches, I draw the lines by using this code.

```
(...some code...)

//draw good matches
for( int i = 0; i < (int)good_matches.size(); i++ )
{ 

   printf( "-- Good Match [%d] Keypoint 1: %d  -- Keypoint 2: %d  \n", i, good_matches[i].queryIdx,  good_matches[i].trainIdx ); 

   //query image is the first frame
   Point2f point_old = keypoints_1[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt;

   //train  image is the next frame that we want to find matched keypoints
   Point2f point_new = keypoints_2[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt;

   //keypoint color for frame 1: RED
   circle(img_1, point_old, 3, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);  
   circle(img_2, point_old, 3, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);  

   //keypoint color for frame 2: BLUE
   circle(img_1, point_new, 3, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);  
   circle(img_2, point_new, 3, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1); 

   //draw a line between keypoints
   line(img_1, point_old, point_new, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);
   line(img_2, point_old, point_new, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0); 
}
  imwrite("directory/image1.jpg",img_1);
  imwrite("directory/image2.jpg",img_2);

(...some code...)
```

I saved the results to the first (img_1) and next frame (img_2). As you see, I have different results, but the line shape is same. In video homography sample of OpenCV, keypoint tracking seems accurate. They follow this approach:**detect keypoints-->compute keypoints-->warp keypoints--> match--> find homography-->draw matches**. However, I apply **detect keypoints-->compute keypoints-->match-->draw matches**.
I am confused if I have to consider homography and perspective  (or other things) to see the keypoint movements accurately.

my results for first frame (img_1) 
[image]

and next frame (img_2)
[image]